# How to import a django model into an external python script

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to be able to import my Django models into an external script to do things such as parse inputted URLs. I have tried creating a python script within the root folder of a Django app and simply importing the model as I would in views.py, however, I keep getting this error:

```
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have searched through the Django docs but so far, I haven't been able to find anything. Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Such work is usually implemented as a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [django.setup()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.setup) before you can use Django models in a stand-alone script

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_app.settings')
django.setup()
```

Comment: And I run this as its own 4 line script or do I include it it any stand-alone script?